# Connect Error in Daytime TCP Client

Tags: c, sockets, network-programming

What am I doing wrong because I cant get the daytime output. Code looks fine to me. Also why do we give third parameter in inet_pton as **&serverAddress.sin_addr** and not **&serverAddress.sin_addr.s_addr** ?

```
#include    <stdio.h>
#include    <stdlib.h>
#include    <string.h>
#include    <sys/socket.h>
#include    <sys/time.h>
#include    <sys/types.h>
#include    <netinet/in.h>
#include    <arpa/inet.h>
#include    <errno.h>
#include    <unistd.h>

#define MAXLINE 4096

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int sockfd, n;
    char receiveLine[MAXLINE +1];
    struct sockaddr_in serverAddress;

    if(argc != 2)
    {
        printf("\nUsage: a.out <IPaddress>\n");                                  //First Argument is FileName, Second should be IP Address
        exit(0);
    }

    if( (sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0)
    {       
        printf("Socket error\n");
        exit(0);
    }

    bzero(&serverAddress, sizeof(serverAddress));
    serverAddress.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serverAddress.sin_port = htons(4455);

    if(inet_pton(AF_INET, argv[1], &serverAddress.sin_addr) <= 0)            //Presentation to Network.
    {   
        printf("inet_pton error for %s",argv[1]);
        exit(0);
    }

    if(connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&serverAddress, sizeof(serverAddress))<0)
    {
        printf("connect error");
        exit(0);
    }

    while( (n = read(sockfd, receiveLine, MAXLINE)) > 0)
    {
        receiveLine[n] = 0;
        if(fputs(receiveLine, stdout) == EOF)
        {       
            printf("fputs error");
            exit(0);
        }
    }

    if(n < 0)
    {   
        printf("read error");
        exit(0);
    }
    exit(0);    
}
```

Comment: What error you are getting? print errno and see.

Comment: Is the server supposed to send some day-time string?

Comment: @kiranBiradar It says "Connection Refused" when i used **perror**

Comment: And you did connect to a server with a working (open) daytime server, right?  Verified using netcat or similar?  It's usually on port 13, not 4455...

Comment: @TobySpeight I changed port to 13 later and verified with netcat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(Posted solution on behalf of the question author)*.

I was dumb enough to forget about the listening port. Used "nc -l localhost 4455".